# Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow C$. Prove that if $g\circ f$ is a bijection, then $g$ is surjective.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose $g\circ f$ is a bijection. Then we have that $g(f(a)) = g(f(b))$

If I was proving $f$ is $1-1$ I would go on to show that $a = b$, but I'm not sure how to prove that g is surjective here.

Comment: You want to prove that g is subjective, right? Please edit the title.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $y\in C$. Then as $g \circ f$ is a bijection, there exists $x\in A$ such that $g(f(x))=y$.

Comment: To really spell it out: let $$\xi=f(x).$$

Answer (score 0):

> If I was proving f is 1−1 I would go on to show that a=b, but I'm not sure how to prove that g is surjective here.

So to prove $g$ is surjective, you would prove for every $c \in C$ there is a $b\in B$ so that $g(b) = c$.

Now $g\circ f$ is bijective so it is surjective, so for any $c \in C$ there is an $a\ in A$ so that $g(f(a)) = c$.... so $f(a) \in B$ and $g(f(a)) = c$ so $b  = f(a)$ is the $b$ we needed to show exists.